# Text looks bold in IE9 after rotation

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, rotation, internet-explorer-9

I have some vertical text. In IE9 it looks like bold text. And if text don't rotate it looks normal. How can I fix this IE feature?
I use the follow rotating:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=3.061515884555943e-16, M12=1, M21=-1, M22=3.061515884555943e-16, SizingMethod='auto expand')";
```

Text's computed styles are:

```
display: block;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
height: 20px;
line-height: 20px;
```

Comment: Can we see a jsFiddle or a live link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Don't use `-ms-filter` to rotate things in IE9.

IE9 supports the CSS standard `transform:rotate()` style ([as `-ms-transform`](http://caniuse.com/transforms2d)), so you should use that instead.

The old `-ms-filter` styles are well known to have bugs and glitches, and this kind of thing is exactly the sort of glitch they're famous for. If you're using `-ms-filter`, don't be surprised when you get things like this.

In older IE versions (IE8 and earlier) you do need to use `-ms-filter` (or just `filter`), and you would have to live with glitches like this if you really wanted to do rotation.

But in IE9, you don't need it; it supports the standard CSS, so use that instead. Much better compatibility and fewer rendering glitches. Problem solved.

If you're currently using standard CSS rotation *and* `-ms-filter` in the same CSS code, then this also can cause problems -- having them both together is known to cause issues, as the browser tries to do them both and ends up getting it all horribly wrong.

This is because IE9 supports both the old `-ms-filter` style and the new transform style. But if you try to do them both at the same time, it gets completely confused. The problem doesn't exist in IE10 because IE10 no longer supports the `-ms-filter` styles.

If you are using both because you need to support IE8 as well as newer browsers, then you should consider using something IE8-specific for the `-ms-filter` style so that IE9 doesn't see it. The easiest option would probably be to have an IE-version class in your `<body>` tag, using IE conditional comments, and put the `-ms-filter` style into `.ie8 #rotateme` (where your current selector would be `#rotateme`; change as necessary).

Another option for IE8 is to use the [CSS Sandpaper](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/tag/css-sandpaper/) polyfill library, which backports the CSS standard rotation styles into IE8. It uses `filter` behind the scenes, but it means your actual CSS code doesn't need to have the filter in the code, so you won't need to do anything special with it for IE8/9 compatibilty.

Comment: @thirtydot - no worries; I've put the paragraph back. :)  (and thanks for correcting the typo)

Answer (score 0):

Add a `font-weight:normal;`

For Instance,

```
display: block;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
height: 20px;
line-height: 20px;
font-weight:normal; /* Add this to normalize the boldness of your fonts. */
```

This will hopefully solve your purpose.

Comment: Nothing changed after that :(